# Ajax requests are not made on page load when using KnockoutJS

Tags: ajax, json, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, cors

I am new to the whole front-end client scripting scene and have encountered a few difficulties when working on my most recent project.  I have looked around the website and could not find anything that answered my question.  There may be something here and I have just not found it because of my inexperience and if there is it would be nice if you can provide a link to those resources.

I am currently working on building a client that makes ajax calls to a cross-domain asp.net web api that I have built.  I know that the web api works as it has been tested in fiddler.  I have also managed to successfully make calls on a click event.

The problem is that I cannot seem to get this working on page load and with knockoutjs.  I have tried to do a simple list that is populated with data when the page loads but when I load the page and check fiddler I can see that the ajax calls are not being made.  This possibly explains why when I load the page the content isn't there.  I have tried inserting some static data to view model and the binding worked so it seems it may be the case that there is something blocking the ajax calls.

I have looked at examples and have knocked up some code.  I cannot see any problems with the code but as I am inexperienced there is certainly a possibility that I am missing something.  There may also be more efficient ways to do model binding, if so, I would appreciate any advice from someone more experienced.

The code is:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "KnockoutTesting";
}


<!-- MAIN -->
    <div id="main">
        <!-- wrapper-main -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: places">
                <li>
                    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function PlacesViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        function Place(root, id, title, description, url, pub) {
            var self = this;

            self.id = id;
            self.title = ko.observable(title);
            self.description = ko.observable(description);
            self.url = ko.observable(url);
            self.pub = ko.observable(pub);

            self.remove = function () {
                root.sendDelete(self);
            };

            self.update = function (title, description, url, pub) {
                self.title(title);
                self.description(description);
                self.url(url);
                self.pub(pub);
            };

        };

        self.places = ko.observableArray();

        self.add = function (id, title, description, url, pub) {
            self.places.push(new Place(self, id, title, description, url, pub));
        };

        self.remove = function (id) {
            self.places.remove(function (place) { return place.id === id; });
        };

        self.update = function (id, title, description, url, pub) {
            var oldItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.places(), function (i) { return i.id === id; });
            if (oldItem) {
                oldItem.update(title, description, url, pub);
            }
        };



        self.sendDelete = function (place) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:1357/api/places" + place.id,
                type: "DELETE"
            });
        }
    };

    $(function () {
        var viewModel = new PlacesViewModel();

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $JQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.get("http://localhost:1357/api/places", function (places) {
            $.each(places, function (idx, place) {
                viewModel.add(place.PlaceID, place.Title, place.Description, place.URL, place.Public);
            });
        }, "json");
    });

</script>
}
```

It has been simplified for the sake of getting it to work before I add more functionality.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may lie in your Web API implementation. Both the client and the server must support CORS. According to Carlos' [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx), Web API does not natively support CORS. His post includes a code sample.